# Copy icon Photos.app

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, popover, uipasteboard

I'm implementing an image copy function like Photos.app (with UIPasteboard). Like Photos.app I would like to display a "Copy" popover button :

[image]

Is there an official API to create this button or do I have to do it my self ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIMenuController` .